# pthread ошибка при компиляции qtmake

Tags: linux, c, qt, qmake

Пишу многопоточный сервер

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>


void *connection_handler(void *);


int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
 int port;
 int socket_desc, new_socket, s, *new_sock;
 struct sockaddr_in server, client;

 FILE *pFile;
 pFile = fopen("/home/logs", "w");
 if (pFile!=NULL)
  {
       fclose (pFile);
   }


  printf("Введите номер порта сервера: ");
  scanf("%d/n", &port);

  /*создаём сокет*/
 socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(s < 0)
{
      perror("Ошибка вызова сокета");
      return 0;
}

 /*определяем прослушиваемый порт и адрес*/
 server.sin_family = AF_INET;
 server.sin_port = htons(port);
 server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
 {
      perror("Ошибка соеденения");
      return 0;
  }

  /*слушаем порт*/
  listen(socket_desc, 5);
  puts("Ожидание входящих соединений...");

  /*читаем данные из сокета*/
  s = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client,    (socklen_t*)&s)))
  {
      puts("Соединение принято");

      pthread_t sniffer_thread;
      new_sock = malloc(1);
      *new_sock = new_socket;

      if(pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL,  connection_handler, (void*) new_sock)   < 0)
      {
          perror("Поток не создан");
          return 1;
       }



  }

     return 0;
  }


   void *connection_handler(void *new_socket)
{
   char buffer[100];

for(;;)
 {
   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
  int rc = recv(new_socket, buffer, 100, 0);
  if( rc < 0 )
 {
        
        if(errno == EINTR )
                continue;
        perror("Не могу получить данные.");
        return 0;
  }

   if( rc == 0 )
        break;
   printf("%s\n", buffer);


  // строка для записи в файл
   char * message = buffer;
   // файл для записи
   char * filename = "/home/logs";
   // запись в файл
   FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
   if(fp)
   {
       // записываем строку
       fputs(message, fp);
       fclose(fp);

   }
 }

 free(new_socket);

 return 0;
 }
```

при запуске выдаёт

> undefined reference to `pthread_create'

использую компилятор qmake как я понимаю билотека pthread не подтягиваеться нужно что то прописать в настроечном файле Makefile но вот что и в каком месте файла?
А если запустить через командную строку то выдаёт ошибку

> In function ‘connection_handler’:
> /home/QtProjects/server/main.c:87:23: warning: passing argument 1 of
> ‘recv’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> int rc = recv(new_socket, buffer, 100, 0);
> ^ In file included from /home/QtProjects/server/main.c:2:0:
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:156:16: note: expected
> ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’  extern ssize_t recv (int __fd,
> void *__buf, size_t __n, int __flags);

Comment: Для gcc/g++ в командной строке надо задать флаг `-pthread` (кстати, это написано в самом начале manpage)